# Seams of print are underextruded causing large pits/gaps? (Prusa Mk3+, Prusa Slicer)

Tags: prusa-i3, underextrusion, prusaslicer

The seams on my print are much larger than they were a few months ago and I'm not sure what's going on or how to fix it.

Pic with seams random:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/PvmpsWb.png]

With aligned seams:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/1GIDDz9.png]

I'm using the 0.2 mm QUALITY profile with the following adjustments:

- 200 °C temp
- Perimeters lower speed (25 mm/s inner, 15 mm/s outer; prevents small overhang warping, faster speeds don't really ease the issue anyway)
- First layer speed slow (10 mm/s)
- Retraction Z lift 0.2 mm (default 0.4 mm; helps stringing)
- Using Jessie PLA (Printed solid)
- Filament is dry, fresh out the dehydrator

[My full slicer settings found here](https://pastebin.com/fZhZXRAP).

I've tried lowering the retraction speed, increasing it, increasing the detraction speed to 2x, raising temp, and calibration of the linear advance according to the calibration test print on Prusa's website.

What I can do to make gaps smaller?

Comment: do you have a Prusa made i3?

Comment: I ask, because direct drive has differences from bowden style. Also, we'd need retraction length.

Comment: @Trish Yes, I posted the printer model in the title along with the tag. My full settings I linked in the post which contains the retraction length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to more or less solve it by using the "extra length on restart" property set to 0.1 mm. Sort of "primes" the filament after a retraction by moving it forward a bit.

To lesser effect I reduced retraction distance from 0.8 to 0.5, lowered retraction speed from 35 to 10, and upped detraction speed from 35 to 50.

[image]

Left object is with new settings, right object is original issue.